# Booking a time slot for meeting

Tags: view, view-styles

I want to create something like a calendar view to show list of all open time slots (Slot's are 15 minutes) and should be able to click a button to reserve/Block any open slot, up to 3 business days prior to the meeting date
-Reserve button should be disabled 3 business days prior to the meeting date.

Is this possible using a normal calendar view available in sharepoint 2013. If so, could you please guide with the steps I have to follow.